# What's the difference between a PhoneGap plugin and addJavascriptInterface?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We've built PhoneGap plugins to communicate from our Javascript code back to our Java code. I know that Android also has an `addJavascriptInterface` function. Documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

Is the only difference between the two that the PhoneGap plugin is asynchronous while the Javascript interface is synchronous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the PhoneGap team would prefer to use addJavascriptInterface but there is a [bug in Android 2.3 where it is broken](http://quitenoteworthy.blogspot.com/2010/12/handling-android-23-webviews-broken.html). That's why we have our work around in place so you'll be able to build hybrid apps regardless of the version of Android you are running on.

Comment: Thanks for that link -- out of curiosity, has it been confirmed to happen for any devices, or merely the emulator?

Comment: I have not run across a device that's had the problem but other folks on the PhoneGap google group had reported the problem.